# Unable to convert very small string value to decimal with NumberFormatter Swift4

Tags: swift, numberformatter

I try to convert string  "0.0004131955" to decimal/double/currency with NumberFormatter. It produces nil.

How to convert it?

My sample code is as below:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale.current
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 15
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true

//number is nil here
if let number = formatter.number(from: "0.0004131955") {
   let unitPrice = number.doubleValue        
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `formatter.numberStyle = .currency` — the string doesn't look like currency formatted to me.

Comment: Also, `formatter.locale = Locale.current` — are you sure the string will always be formatted in user's current locale?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the currency from numberStyle - copy to a playground to test

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale.current
//formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 15
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true

let number: NSNumber? = formatter.number(from: "0.0004131955")
let unitPrice: Double? = number?.doubleValue
```

[image]

Comment: it is still nil @Damo

Comment: it's a good question but in my defence the original author only asks about that particular string and not any variable localised string....

Answer (score 0):

HI @erdemgc for Number stlye Deciamal your code is working fine for me you can check console in below image [image]

and for the currency you have to specify a currency style format you  for Example  i am attaching a image please take a look of below description 
[image]